# Can Tailwind CSS be used in a React Native project?

Tags: react-native

I'm currently working on a **React Native** project and exploring styling options. I've been using Tailwind CSS for **web development**, and I'm wondering if there's a way to integrate or use a similar **utility-first approach in React Native.**

Is there a way to implement **Tailwind CSS** or a **similar utility-first** framework in a React Native project? If not, what are some alternative approaches or libraries that provide a comparable development experience in terms of rapid styling and utility classes?

I've tried searching online, but I couldn't find a clear solution, so any guidance or **insights from the community** would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: There is actually a simple solution. I suggest you look at this resource : https://www.nativewind.dev/overview/

Answer (score 0):

Yes,follow these steps:

1. Install nativewind and it's peer dependency tailwindcss by running:

   yarn add nativewind
   yarn add --dev tailwindcss
2. Run

   npx tailwindcss init

   to create a **tailwind.config.js** file
3. Modify **babel.config.js**

   module.exports = function (api) {
   api.cache(true);
   return {
   presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],

   - plugins: ["nativewind/babel"],
     };
     };

For reference check the [official documentation](https://www.nativewind.dev/quick-starts/expo?fbclid=IwAR1rewV7ICVSp-fD3eU1QyNAjIqNbhAUggOwoexmy5Z4oxzCJsvAo4R-uPA#expo-web):